# Custom Font Acts Weird In Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, browser, safari, custom-font

I have a custom font on my site I'm working on that appears to be bolded for no reason. Please note: visit the site on Safari on a Mac. http://lukaszw.siteground.net/lbp/ Scroll over the "About Us" link and the font looks like it turns from bold to normal. Any idea why this is happening? And any way to get the font to be the "normal" look.

Comment: Where's the code that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  padding-top: 80px;
  color: #34495e;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}


a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  font-weight:bold;/*should fix this*/
}
```